# Wp-admin/admin-AJAX 403 forbidden

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Ajax request raised from WordPress logged in user works properly. But non-logged in user ajax request fails with 403 forbidden.
We tried the following solution: 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-ajax-php-403-forbidden-2/
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/345194/403-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-wp-admin-admin-ajax-php-on

Our site connected to Azure AD. Redirect to our server.
.config file

````
        ServerAdmin ****
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName blog.xxxx.com
    ServerAlias blog.xxx.com

        Redirect permanent / https://domain/blogs

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin ***
    ServerName blog.xxx.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile privatekey.key

        <Directory /var/www/html/>

            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>```
````

Comment: Have you checked by disable all plugins. After disabling all plugins is not solving your problems then please check on default theme.

Comment: Also please check file and folder permission. Every folder permission should be 755 and file permission should be 644.

Comment: Do you have a firewall/security plugin installed on your site?

Comment: @cabrerahector we didn't install any security plugin.

Comment: @dineshkashera  same file permission we followed. but still, have that  403 issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed any plugin and you haven't changed or added a custom code to your template then
1. Check the .htaccess file on the directory
2. Go to admin and then to pages,Check the home Page access Level.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > WP Super Cache > Advanced (tab)

scroll down to **Cache Timeout**
change 3600 to 1800 or use lower value and click

**Change Expiration**

This should help